# Angular - Webpack definePlugin variable is not defined

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm trying to inject variables into my code through Webpack's definePlugin.

And after reading numerous posts nothing seems to work. I have a feeling I'm missing something...

My webpack config is -

```
webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      $TEST: JSON.stringify(true),
      $ENV: {
        ENVIRONMENT: JSON.stringify(process.env.ENVIRONMENT) || 'localhost',
        API_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL)
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

I created `typing.d.ts` file to declare variables :

```
declare let $ENV: Env;
declare let $TEST: boolean;

interface Env {
  ENVIRONMENT: string;
  API_URL: string;
}
```

then i'm trying to log variables in my main.ts file :

```
console.log('Test ' + $TEST);
console.log('Environment :', $ENV.ENVIRONMENT);
```

But I receive the next error when launch 'ng serve' command

[image]

I'm using :

- webpack : 5.54.0
- "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^12.1.2",
- "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.7",
- "@angular/cli": "~12.2.7",

Does anyone has any idea to fix it please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only work for `ng build`, for `ng serve` we will need to add another custom angular-builder to our angular.json:

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          }
        },
```

Important, some other posts mentions to use `@angular-builders/dev-server:generic` builder.

But this one is deprecated (see [angular-builders migration](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/blob/master/MIGRATION.MD))

> @angular-builders/dev-server:generic has been deprecated. Use
> @angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server instead.